# How to Pivot the SQL Data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have a dataset related to surveys and I have to create a view on them. The dataset is in the format:

```
surveyID    RID    Question   Answer     Comment
-----------------------------------------------------------------
17     |   123  |   Q1     |   0      |
17     |   123  |   Q2     |          |   The salesperson and manager was very considerate and I will be coming back for my next car!
17     |   123  |   Q3     |   5      |   Very bad behavior
```

The required result is as

```
surveyID |   RID  |  Q1  |  Q1_c |  Q2  |  Q2_c  |  Q3  |  Q3_c 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
17       |   123  |  0   |       |      | The... |  5   | Very...
```

The Questions and questions comment should be in the header row as above:

I have tried to get the result but I succeed only if I pivot for 1 column i.e the Answer column but how to pivot the answer and comment columns simultaneously?

This is the query which I have done

```
select rid, surveyid, --comment,    
    Q1,Q2,Q3
from
(
  select rid, surveyid, question, --comment,    
    value
  from
  (
    select rid, surveyid, question, -- comment,
      answer      
    from #temp
  ) s
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (answer)
  ) un
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for question in (Q1, Q2, Q3)
) piv
```

And the result is as:

```
surveyID |   RID  |  Q1  |  Q2  |  Q3  |  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
17       |   123  |  0   |      |  5   |
```

Comment: Have you tried pivotting the comments in separate sub-queries/CTEs from the answers and then joining the two subqueries/CTEs together?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another alternative, since SQL Server doesn't have an easy way to do a multi-column pivot with the pivot operator, you can always revert to performing a hand coded pivot"

```
select surveyID, rid
     , max(case question when 'Q1' then answer end) q1
     , max(case question when 'Q1' then comment end) q1_c
     , max(case question when 'Q2' then answer end) q2
     , max(case question when 'Q2' then comment end) q2_c
     , max(case question when 'Q3' then answer end) q3
     , max(case question when 'Q3' then comment end) q3_c
  from #temp
 group by surveyID, rid
```

It's actually more compact than the other options presented so far and possibly has better performance, though you'd need to test that assertion for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I split the query into two similar pivots, pivot the data in CTEs, and then join the CTEs together.

```
;WITH QnA AS
(
    SELECT
        RID
        ,surveyID
        ,Q1
        ,Q2
        ,Q3
    FROM
    ( SELECT RID, surveyID, Question, Answer FROM #temp ) src
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Answer)
        FOR Question IN ( Q1
            ,Q2
            ,Q3
        )
    ) piv
)
,QnAComments AS
(
    SELECT
        RID
        ,surveyID
        ,Q1_c = Q1
        ,Q2_c = Q2
        ,Q3_c = Q3
    FROM
    ( SELECT RID, surveyID, Question, Comment FROM #temp ) src
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Comment)
        FOR Question IN ( Q1
            ,Q2
            ,Q3
        )
    ) piv
)
SELECT
    QnA.surveyID
    ,QnA.RID
    ,Q1
    ,Q1_c
    ,Q2
    ,Q2_c
    ,Q3
    ,Q3_c
FROM QnA
INNER JOIN QnAComments ON QnAComments.RID = QnA.RID
                           AND QnAComments.surveyID = QnA.surveyID
```

Answer (score 1):

When you unpivot your data, you can combine the question and Col columns into a single column for use in the pivot operation like this:

```
select * from (
  select surveyid, rid, question+'_'+col QC, value from (
    select rid, surveyid, question, Comment,
      cast(answer as varchar(91)) Answer
    from #temp
  ) s
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (Answer, Comment)
  ) un
  ) src
 pivot
(
  max(value)
  for QC in (Q1_Answer, Q1_Comment, Q2_Answer, Q2_Comment, Q3_Answer, Q3_Comment)
) piv
```

You can get your desired column headings with some minor tweaks:

```
select * from (
  select surveyid, rid, question+case col when 'comment' then '_c' end QC, value from (
    select rid, surveyid, question, Comment,
      cast(answer as varchar(91)) Answer
    from #temp
  ) s
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (Answer, Comment)
  ) un
  ) src
 pivot
(
  max(value)
  for QC in (Q1, Q1_C, Q2, Q2_C, Q3, Q3_C)
) piv
```